# SU command issue in Android device

Tags: android, shell, root

I want to change the folder permissions on device but when I type su I get permission denied is there any other way to do the same?

Comment: just wanted to know what i am doing wrong i know its very basic question but still no luck

Comment: Your question is very fuzzy and seems to be of a general "computer help" nature.

Comment: http://www.redhat.com/docs/manuals/linux/RHL-9-Manual/getting-started-guide/s1-navigating-ownership.html this might help you.

What exactly do you mean by device?

Comment: there is an adb commanld line from whcih we can access the folders of emulator and device and add files to it i am able to us it on emulator but on device it is givving security issue

Comment: hi ,
     has anybody faced this problem ...
  Thnx in advance

Comment: What exact device are you using? I would expect the security policies on consumer devices to be radically different than the ones on development devices or prototypes.

Comment: Most likely your phone is not rooted. Once it is rooted you will be able to use "su".

Answer (score 2):

As there are not too many Android devices available at the moment I'm guessing you are talking about an HTC Dream (aka G1). It looks like you don't have root access on that device which is normal unless it is a developer phone (ADP1).

It is [possible](http://www.google.com/search?q=root+g1) to get root access on your T-Mobile G1 however, just takes some effort.